# Stop remounting of a component on a conditional render

Tags: reactjs

Is there a way other than CSS `display: none` to conditionally render without remounting of a component?

I have an example where I have this component getting remounted instead of rerendered whenever I conditionally display a loading element. [Here's a working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-jennings-ne67y?file=/src/App.js:69-721).

This becomes a problem whenever my component has some validation states. It triggers the loading element but then remounts and the validation state is being reset because it is mounted again with the default values.

I have figured I can just have a style attribute `style={{ display: isLoading ? 'none' : 'block' }}` on the Component but that's not an approach I find 'correct'.

```
const App = () => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

  const toggle = async () => {
    setIsLoading(true);

    await new Promise((resolve) => {
      return setTimeout(() => {
        resolve();
      }, 1500);
    });

    setIsLoading(false);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={toggle}>Toggle Loading</button>
      {isLoading ? <div>Loading...</div> : <Component />}
    </div>
  );
}

const Component = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Component mounted.");
    return () => console.log("Component unmounted.");
  }, []);
  return <div>Component</div>;
};
```

Comment: Read this https://reacttraining.com/blog/mount-vs-render/

Comment: @RajendranNadar I did read the article and do get the point it unmounts the component since it's no longer part of the `App`'s return. My question still stands whether there's a way to render the component without the use of 'hiding' the element with CSS.

Comment: My guy, you got it all wrong. You YOURSELF, with your own hands, are unmounting/re-mounting the **Component** through that conditional render. Mounting is when you add something in the DOM: unmounting is when you remove something from the DOM. When *isLoading* is TRUE, *Component* is not rendered, hence it's unmounted. When *isLoading* is FALSE, *Component* is rendered/showed, hence mounted.

Answer (score 0):

To preserve the state & conditionally render I would suggest you to store the local state in the parent component, & pass it down to the child component. Something like this.

```
const App = () => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

  // Some const values for validation
  const [isValid, setValid] = useState(false); //<--- Here

  const toggle = async () => {
    setIsLoading(true);

    await new Promise((resolve) => {
      return setTimeout(() => {
        resolve();
      }, 1500);
    });

    setIsLoading(false);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={toggle}>Toggle Loading</button>
      {isLoading ? <div>Loading...</div> : <Component isValid={isValid} setValid={setValid} />}
    </div>
  );
}

const Component = ({ isValid, setValid }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Component mounted.");
    return () => console.log("Component unmounted.");
  }, []);
  return <div>Component</div>;
};
```